# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined … in subflow module

Tags: node-red

I created a subflow and packed it as a module accordingly to the howto in the nodered docs.

https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/subflow-modules#add-your-subflow-json

If I add the node to the flow and deploy it, I will get an TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_originalWires').

With a more complex subflow the property which is not readable changes but it is all the time a TypeError: Cannot read,...

So, the flow works fine as a subflow but stops working packed as a module. You can find an example for this issue ob my gitlab account for direct installation as a nodered module:

https://github.com/buhln/node-red-subflow-example/

`npm install buhln/node-red-subflow-example`

Perhaps someone ran in the same issue and found a solution.

Comment: This will be better raised as an issue and include all the version information